CPLEX CP Optimizer's search phase doesn't support Restart SearchType
CPLEX CP Optimizer allows users to set search phases to specify the order in which variables are searched and the method for assigning values, thereby accelerating the search process.
However, when using the Restart or Auto SearchType, tests have shown that the information passed in the search phase is not utilized by the solver. See the following example code:
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel, step_at
from docplex.cp.modeler import search_phase, var_index, value, select_smallest

model = CpoModel()
ivs = []  # store intervals
sts = []  # store start times of intervals
occupy = step_at(0, 0)
for i in range(10):
    iv = model.interval_var(size=1)
    st = model.integer_var(min=0)
    model.add(st == model.start_of(iv))
    ivs.append(iv)
    sts.append(st)
    occupy += model.pulse(iv, 1)
model.add(occupy <= 1)  # all intervals do not overlap
phase_1 = search_phase(
    [sts[i] for i in range(5, 10)],
    select_smallest(var_index([sts[i] for i in range(5, 10)])),
    select_smallest(value()),
)
phase_2 = search_phase(
    [sts[i] for i in range(5)],
    select_smallest(var_index([sts[i] for i in range(5)])),
    select_smallest(value()),
)
model.set_search_phases([phase_1, phase_2])
model.set_parameters({"Workers": 1, "SearchType": "Restart"})
result = model.solve()
for i in range(10):
    iv = ivs[i]
    print(f"{i + 1}-th interval: {result.get_value(iv)}")

This example includes 10 interval variables, which are divided into 2 search phases. Intervals 6 to 10 are in phase 1 and are to be searched first, while intervals 1 to 5 are in phase 2 and are to be searched subsequently. Additionally, each interval is assigned the smallest possible value.
The expected result is that the start times of intervals 6 to 10 (phase 1) should be 0, 1, ..., 4, respectively, and the start times of intervals 1 to 5 (phase 2) should be 5, 6, ..., 9, respectively. However, the actual result is:
1-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=0, end=1, size=1)
2-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=1, end=2, size=1)
3-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=2, end=3, size=1)
4-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=3, end=4, size=1)
5-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=4, end=5, size=1)
6-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=5, end=6, size=1)
7-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=6, end=7, size=1)
8-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=7, end=8, size=1)
9-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=8, end=9, size=1)
10-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=9, end=10, size=1)

If change the SearchType from Restart to DepthFirst, the expected result appears:
1-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=5, end=6, size=1)
2-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=6, end=7, size=1)
3-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=7, end=8, size=1)
4-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=8, end=9, size=1)
5-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=9, end=10, size=1)
6-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=0, end=1, size=1)
7-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=1, end=2, size=1)
8-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=2, end=3, size=1)
9-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=3, end=4, size=1)
10-th interval: IntervalVarValue(start=4, end=5, size=1)

, so I suspect that search phase feature and Restart are not compatible. Is there a way to still pass domain knowledge (which is what the search phase does) to the solver when using the Restart SearchType?

The only way to have a strategy that rigorously follows the search phases is
to use DFS, because the only strategy in DFS is tree search : choose a variable, instantiate it to a value and backtrack if an inconsistency is detected.
However, when solving a scheduling model with default search (Restart), for being efficient, tree search is not the only way to search, there are different strategies, including local search that can be used. As a consequence, the phases order and strategy given are used only when instantiating integer variables with tree search. The search can even start by instantiating interval variables and instantiate integers afterwards and this is what happens in your case.
